# Seemingly useless line in C++ Direct X 12 Samples code

Tags: c++, directx-12

In one of the files of the Direct X Samples "MiniEngine" ( https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/MiniEngine ) I found this line that confused me:

```
void CameraController::Update( float deltaTime )
{
    (deltaTime); // <-- here
    …
}
```

At first I thought it was something to make the compiler stop complaining about an unused parameter, but it is used further down anyway.
I can only think it is some sort of performance optimisation somehow, but I can't think what.

Can anyone enlighten me?  It could always be a new C++ thing I don't know about :)  I haven't played with C++ for about 10 years.

Comment: Can you link the exact file and line? Maybe the commit history would have some explanation?

Comment: [https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/CameraController.cpp#L58](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/CameraController.cpp#L58)

Comment: Most likely they don’t use the given argument so this is to make warnings of unused arguments go away

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: But that would result in another warning in GCC at least: `<source>:5:6: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: The whole file was added in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/commit/63384e3af458cede33d292d6252c3ea661365f79#diff-9cc16b5481f1b77735defc3cbd6786c4) commit. So commit message has no hints.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, it may be used to mute warnings about unused variable, however it would be better if it was written:

`(void) deltaTime;`

That should mute warnings on most (if not all) compilers.

Comment: It's possible that it's a remnant of when the code was not yet completed. As it is now, it gets used further on in the function anyway.